# could not render the wait screen in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

```
function Events(){
const [items, setItems] = useState([])
const fetchItems = async () =>{
    const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.cypress.io/todos/')
    const items = await data.json();
    return items         
}

useEffect(() =>{ 
    fetchItems().then((items) =>{
        setItems(items)});
},[]
);
if (items ===null) {
    return <h2>Loading posts...</h2>;
  }

return (
    <div>
        {items.map(item=>           
        <h1 key = {item.id}>
            <Link to={`/Events/${item.id}`}>{item.title} </Link>
        </h1>          
        )}
    </div>
);
```

In the given code the If statement is not running when it is fetching from the api. I am fairly new to react and JavaScript please help me find out my mistake

Comment: items is an empty array, as you have initialised it as empty array. Try changing your condition to `if (!items.length) ...`

Comment: but when i tried `if(items === [])` still i was not getting the output

Comment: because `[] === []` is false, that's js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simply:

```
return (
    <div>
        {items ? items.map(item=>           
        <h1 key = {item.id}>
            <Link to={`/Events/${item.id}`}>{item.title} </Link>
        </h1>          
        ) : <h2>Loading Posts...</h2>}
    </div>
);
```